# How does this end effector work?

Tags: design, mechanism, joint

I've seen this linear actuator end effector on a few industrial SCARA 'bots but I am having trouble visualizing how it works internally:

[image: Linear Actuator]

It looks like a type of lead screw, but the nut must spin instead of the rod to cause motion. If this is the case would the end part of the effector not also spin with the rod? Does this end effector design have a specific name ? If you can explain how the mechanics of this joint works It would be very helpful.

All help appreciated.

Edit:
Sorry for the low res picture, more detail about the type of joint im looking at can be found at:

Models that have this type of joint include the [Epson T3](https://www.epson.co.uk/products/robot/epson-scara-t3-series)

[Epson T3 Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDGp1S8lnn0)

[Fanuc SR-3iA](https://www.fanuc.eu/uk/en/robots/robot-filter-page/scara-series/scara-sr-3ia)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, kp122. You've posted a low-resolution image and it's hard for me to see the actuator in detail. You stated you found a few robots with this style of end effector; could you please post some model numbers and/or links to datasheets?

Comment: Thanks @Chuck , I have edited the post to include more info about the type of machines I'm asking about.

Comment: i remember answering this exact question a year or so ago ... looking for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actuator has two raceways cut into it.

One is a screw thread, and engages with a rotary screw nut that is turned by a motor. Turning the nut moves the actuator linearly.

The other is a spline groove and is cut parallel to the actuator axis, and engages with a rotary spine nut that is turned by another motor. Turning the nut spins the actuator on its axis

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=BALL+SCREW+SPLINE+SPBR&iax=images&ia=images

---

https://euro-bearings.com/lin_SPBR.html

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much @jsotola. Is this type of shaft preferred to a regular CNC lead screw because of torque and/or precision ? Though CNC machines have the same precision and higher torque needs generally. Any idea why this type of shaft is so widely used ?

Comment: it is not a lead screw ... it is a robotic arm ... a manipulator would be mounted on the end of the shaft

Comment: Thanks very much, really appreciate it @jsotola

Comment: this is supperior in most performance characteristics when compared to a lead screw. Just for completeness sake, high-en CNCs use ball screws not lead screws!